# When opening a 'child window' from the main site do i have to create an HTML page for each child window or is there a way to make it generate its own?

Tags: javascript, html

I am programming a website that has products for sale and need to know how to specifically set up child windows. Do i have to create a child window for EACH image or is there a standard page that the code can assign it to?

Answer (score 0):

Using "popup" windows can be troublesome.. some browsers will not open them properly due to their internal "popup blockers"

but to answer your question. if you set the URL of the window to the image itself it should load in the window without the need for a page.

i.e. http://www.example.com/img/myimage.jpg

A better way to do this would be using a javascript library such as jQuery and jQuery-UI to open modal overlays.